# ASP.NET Submitting Form - Status Code 302 Found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple form. When i submit empty form (for testing validations) using a post request ...

It doesn't shows the validation messages and also return status Code 302.
and also generate some random quesry string. something like this:

`http://localhost:49852/Events/Create?Type=0&details=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSampleProject.Models.Type%5D`

This satuation i have never seen before!

```
@{Html.BeginForm("Save", "Event" , FormMethod.post);}

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix these problems.")

    // fields...
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

@{Html.EndForm();}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EventFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Save",viewModel);

    //..additional Code.

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: is that HTML code that you have? or missed?

Comment: `return RedirectToAction` of course it redirects (with 302), you tell it to do so. You’ll need to handle the POST properly within your action instead of redirecting elsewhere.

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale  ithink html code is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that, if `ModelState` is `InValid` you are redirecting to the `Save` method with model data instead of returning the current view with invalid model data.

So write your `Save` `POST` method as follows:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EventFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);

    //..additional Code.

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```